# How do I test this function using mockito and junit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I'm new to mockito and junit5. I'm trying to test the below function:

```
public boolean checkFunction(String element) {

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String uri = "any url im hitting";
    
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

        String json = element;

        StringEntity entity;

        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(json);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "any token");

            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            client.close();

            if (responseBody.contains("any string i wanna check"))
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I tried the below code but I'm unable to get entire code coverage. Also I don't think this is the right approach.

```
@Test
    public void testCheckFunction() throws Exception {
        when(mockClass.checkFunction(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        assertEquals(false, mockclass.checkFunction("dummy"));
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: You're not testing the `checkFunction`, you're mocking it and then testing the mock… instead you'd need to instantiate the real object and mock only it's dependencies (the http client stuff).

Comment: @slauth so you mean that I should treat my mock class same as my original class and instantiate the objects I'm using in the original class in my test too? Can you please show me in demo code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to refactor your code for better testability:

```java
public class Checker {

    private final CloseableHttpClient client;

    public Checker(CloseableHttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public boolean checkFunction(String element) {

        String uri = "http://example.com";

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

        String json = element;

        StringEntity entity;

        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(json);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "any token");

            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            client.close();

            if (responseBody.contains("any string i wanna check"))
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that the dependency (i.e. the thing that has to be mocked in tests) is now injected via the constructor. This way it can easily be replaced by a mock when unit testing this class:

```java
class CheckerTest {

    private final CloseableHttpClient clientMock = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);

    private final Checker checker = new Checker(clientMock);

    @Test
    public void testCheckFunction() throws Exception {
        when(clientMock.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Oops!"));
        assertFalse(checker.checkFunction("dummy"));
    }
}
```